# javascript: call an embedded function from a GM script

Tags: javascript, function, firebug, greasemonkey

On a webpage there's

```
<script>
  function fn982734()
  {
     // some code
  }
</script>
```

In my Greasemonkey script, I have the following code:

```
var fn = fields[5].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute('onclick').substr(7,11);
console.log(fn); // outputs fn982734 to the firebug console
window[fn]();
```

This code does not work, and spawns an error in the error console: window[fn] is not a function. However, typing directly into firebug:

```
var fn = 'fn982734';
window[fn]();
```

works perfectly. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Greasemonkey script is inside a sandbox and Firebug is not.
See: ["Avoid Common Pitfalls" (in Greasemonkey)](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Avoid_Common_Pitfalls).

Your GM script would access that function via `unsafeWindow`.  Like so:

```
unsafeWindow.fn982734();
```

.
Alternatively,

```
var fn = 'fn982734';
unsafeWindow[fn]();
```

Also works -- from inside the Greasemonkey script.

Comment: replacing 'window[func]();' with 'unsafeWindow[func]()' results in a File Not Found error: Firefox can't find the file at jar:file:///usr/lib/firefox-3.6.6/chrome/browser.jar!/content/browser/[uri]

Comment: @Mala: `var fn = 'fn982734';
    unsafeWindow[fn]();` totally works, I double-checked to make sure.  That error message also does not match the code shown.   Paste the **EXACT** Greasemonkey code, and link to the target page.

Comment: Please do not encourage the use of unsafeWindow - it is named **unsafe** for a reason.

Comment: @kwah, `unsafeWindow` is **provided** for a reason. There are many cases when it is the correct or only approach. ... While it is true that an unscrupulous website could *theoretically* exploit the use of unsafeWindow to gain *slightly* elevated privileges... (1) The script author will be able to ID sites that might try such tricks and is forewarned. (2) The odds are very low. The cost/benefit ratio of a webmaster, attempting this exploit, means it will never be used except, maybe, in extreme cases. (3) There are **zero** documented cases of an exploit in the wild and the test case 404's out.

Answer (score 0):

I realise that I'm a little late to this question but Please do not encourage the use of unsafeWindow - it is named **unsafe** for a reason.

The correct alternative would be to use the "location hack" as described on [Greasemonkey's Greasepot Wiki](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Location_hack). This code should correctly call the function described in the original post:

```
location.href = "javascript:void(fn982734())";
```