# How can i call an existing javascript function in greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, xbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript: call an embedded function from a GM script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254112/javascript-call-an-embedded-function-from-a-gm-script)

i'm trying to write a script that will select all friends in the xbox.com message center in order to send a M2AF (message to all friends) without having to manually select all of them.

```
Compose.ToggleFriend('friend1')
```

when run in the url bar (prefixed by javascript: of course) this selects friend1 perfectly.

but when i try to implement this into a greasemonkey script it just won't work for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
unsafeWindow.Compose.ToggleFriend('friend1');
```

unsafeWindow points in GM onto the global window-object.

Comment: I have `mylib.js` with `loadItems(elem, value)` defined. This file is loaded by the main document via `<script src=...>`. And now I want to call `loadItems` with Greasemonkey. I tried this: `unsafeWindow.loadItems( $("select[name='sel1']"), 3);` and get an error `me.selectedIndex is undefined`. I guess the **jQuery** object `$` is in the way... hmmm. Any hints?

Comment: Try **`unsafeWindow.loadItems( unsafeWindow.$("select[name='sel1']"), 3);`**

Comment: it says *unsafeWindow.$ is not a function*. I also tried `unsafeWindow.jQuery`, same thing. I thought I understood it, but... damn. I looked into `jquery.js` and of course, there is a `$` and `jQuery` function defined. hrmmm.

Comment: nah, is a different problem anyway. I used an XPath Query instead of a jQuery-`$` and have the initial *me.selectedIndex is not defined* again. Must be a problem in that `LoadItems` function. thanks anyway.